# How to autowire fields into an aspectj aspect in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, aspectj

I have a Springboot service. I am using Aspectj AOP for access control. I have an aspect class AuthorizationAspect with an autowired field with some access control methods. The autowired field is always null.

Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class AuthorizationAspect {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Around(
        "execution(* some.controller.Method(..))"
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkIfAdmin(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // do something with userService
    }
...
}
```

The field userService is always null.

I've tried adding `@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)` to the Aspect class and adding `<bean id="authorizationAspect" class="com.example.accesscontrol.AuthorizationAspect" factory-method="aspectOf"></bean>` to beans.xml, but nothing seems to work.

How can I resolve this issue?

MCVE: https://github.com/ajones239/SO-MCVE-76996582

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. You said AspectJ, but your aspect seems to be a Spring AOP aspect due to the `@Component` annotation, which would be unnecessary and even counter-productive for a native AspectJ aspect. The way to inject values is also different between the two, so this distinction is important. I suggest to publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, so I can see for myself. Otherwise, you will at best get speculative answers from others, but I do not like to speculate. I prefer to analyse.

Comment: I'll work on an MCVE. I'm definitely using Aspectj, so I suppose the `@Component` is unnecessary.

Comment: @kriegaex
Here is my example.
https://github.com/ajones239/SO-MCVE-76996582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It was key to understanding your situation. I sent you a [pull request](https://github.com/ajones239/SO-MCVE-76996582/pull/1) fixing the problem.

Basically, you need to follow the Spring manual chapter [Using AspectJ to Dependency Inject Domain Objects with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html#aop-atconfigurable) and use `@Configurable` on your native aspect and `@EnableSpringConfigured` on your Spring application. Last but not least, you need a factory method for the native aspect to make it known to Spring:

```java
@Bean
public AuthorizationAspect authorizationAspect() {
  return Aspects.aspectOf(AuthorizationAspect.class);
}
```

The important commit from my PR is [acb5da67](https://github.com/ajones239/SO-MCVE-76996582/pull/1/commits/acb5da6728067be799baecb461370a1ed41779d8).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was actually along the right tracks with a few of the things I tried, but seeing an example was very useful.